# Stuck at Downloaded POS Headers with blk/s = 0 Erigon

Tags: full-node

We are trying to run erigon goerli node, after 2 days it reached block 7999999 and now is stuck at Download PoS Header.

Here is the log:

```
INFO[12-22|06:28:11.875] [LightClient] P2P                        peers=33
INFO[12-22|06:28:41.875] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:29:11.874] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:29:11.875] [txpool] stat                            block=0 pending=0 baseFee=0 queued=0 alloc=1.2GB sys=5.8GB
INFO[12-22|06:29:11.875] [LightClient] P2P                        peers=31
INFO[12-22|06:29:41.874] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:30:11.875] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:30:11.875] [txpool] stat                            block=0 pending=0 baseFee=0 queued=0 alloc=1.1GB sys=5.8GB
INFO[12-22|06:30:11.875] [LightClient] P2P                        peers=33
INFO[12-22|06:30:41.875] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:31:11.874] [Downloader] Downloaded PoS Headers      now=8169226 blk/sec=0.000
INFO[12-22|06:31:11.875] [txpool] stat                            block=0 pending=0 baseFee=0 queued=0 alloc=786.5MB sys
Any possible solution?

@Ali-Shehab

 
Add heading textAdd bold text, <Ctrl+b>Add italic text, <Ctrl+i>
Add a quote, <Ctrl+Shift+.>Add code, <Ctrl+e>Add a link, <Ctrl+k>
Add a bulleted list, <Ctrl+Shift+8>Add a numbered list, <Ctrl+Shift+7>Add a task list, <Ctrl+Shift+l>
Directly mention a user or team
Reference an issue, pull request, or discussion
Add saved reply
Leave a comment
No file chosen
Attach files by dragging & dropping, selecting or pasting them.
Styling with Markdown is supported
Remember, contributions to this repository should follow its contributing guidelines.
Assignees
No one assigned
Labels
None yet
Projects
None yet
Milestone
No milestone
Development
No branches or pull request
```

Comment: hnmm , weird. Goerly moved to PoS (and under PoS you need to run a Beacon client additionally to `geth`) only at block 10,790,00 , you still have 2.8 million blocks to download the chain. anyway, Probably make sense to open a github issue at Erigon repo

Comment: I am running Erigon, I run prysm after getting the error above, should I run them together from the begging? Also, I opened github issue and asked on discord but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests we finally found the issue it was in the configuration file, we forgot to remove txpool.api.url after trying external txpool. Although it was not clear why this should cause a problem.